# exclude sequences depending on description ID in AWK

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have fasta files which have some description ID ( isoforms 2 , ... Isoform 9 ), i want to exclude them in fasta files.

I used this command line to see which file contain the isoform 2 to 9 ID :

```
for i in `ls *.fasta`; do l=`grep 'isoform X[2-9]' $i | head -1`; echo $i $l; done | awk '(NF==1){print}' | head
```

There is a way to include something in my command line for removing them all ?

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Explain what fasta files are

Comment: namefile.fasta : fasta file are files which contrain sequences :
> ID1 isoform 1 
ATCCTGA
> ID2 isoform 2 
ATCCGTAA
> ID3 description
ATCGTC

What i want to have as output is :
> ID1 isoform 1 
ATCCTGA
> ID3 description
ATCGTC

remove all sequences ID which contrain isoform 2 , isoform 3 , isoform 4 until 9 .

Comment: Please DON'T explain what fasta files are but instead simply define your problem in terms of strings in columns and rows of your (to be provided) sample input and expected output and what you want to do with those strings.

Comment: Do all of your fasta files have that same format `<ID> isoform <isoform number> <sequence data>` Or do some of them lack the `isoform <isoform number>` part?

Comment: grep '>' Alligator_sinensis.fasta | head -1
>NP_001273775.1 insulin-like growth factor I [Alligator sinensis]

grep '>' Alligator_sinensis.fasta | grep "isoform" | head -1
>XP_006014705.1 PREDICTED: proline-rich protein 5-like isoform X1 [Alligator sinensis]

Comment: This is exemple of a description of ID the first one are a simple description which doesn't contrain "isoform" into it , the second one contrain isoform X1.
I want to remove all ID which contrain isoform X2 , isoform X3 until isoform X9

Comment: Not all contrain <ID> <isoform  Xnumber> <sequence data>, but some of them.

Comment: Don't iterate over the output of `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/isoform [2-9]\{1,1\}//g' *.fasta
```

Comment: It doesn't work but i write python script and it works.